# What will happen to ROS 1 once Python 2.7 is no more maintained?

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now, whenever I try to install a Python 2.7 package, I get the warning:

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date

There is less than 1 year and, AFAIK, ROS 1 is still the main distribution of ROS (and ROS 2 maybe is not even ready).

What will happen to ROS 1, once Python 2.7 is no more supported? AFAIK, ROS 1 only supports Python 2.7.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318114/what-will-happen-to-ros-1-once-python-2.7-is-no-more-maintained?/) by [nbro](https://answers.ros.org/users/29569/nbro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 372 on 2019-03-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are a couple of very interesting discussions on this topic on ROS Discourse.

[ROS1 to ROS2 transition plan](https://discourse.ros.org/t/discussion-on-ros-to-ros2-transition-plan/6155)

[Planning future ROS1 distributions](https://discourse.ros.org/t/planning-future-ros-1-distribution-s/6538)

Long story short, they plan to release a ROS1 distribution in 2020 with Python3 support.

That N-distribution will probably be the last ROS1 distribution, given the fact that ROS2 is growing very fast and for most of the users it could be already considered stable.

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-03-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0